# Should I use sublime text editor for Web Development in Ubuntu or is there some better editors?

Tags: 14.04, text-editor, sublime-text, web-development, web-design

I want to do some Web Development. I used to have sublime text editor in Windows. Now that i have switched to Ubuntu 14.04.01, I was wondering which is the best test editor to use for easily creating web pages.

Comment: This question is both too broad and too opinion based for this site. You might try the Ubuntu forums or [Ubuntu discourse](http://discourse.ubuntu.com).

Comment: ok. I am new to ubuntu. so I did not know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you felt comfortable using Sublime Text then that is ok to use since the Command Palette and extensibility were clear advantages . From my personal experience i suggest you to try **"vim or emacs"**.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something simpler than sublime but still highlights syntax and has autocomplete, kedit is a good choice.